# Encrypted LUKS volume does not accept password on boot after system freeze

Tags: fedora, luks, disk-encryption, cryptsetup

My Laptop froze and after a hard shutdown the boot process won’t accept my disk encryption password anymore.
I have a ‘standard’ luks-inside-lvm setup, generated while installing fedora, split in a /root, /home and /swap partition, which worked for several years.

Using a live USB system I can access the encrypted volumes and the data seems fine. I haven't had problems using it via chroot.
I ran fsck on the partition for good measure, fstab and crypttab seem fine and haven't changed compared to my backups.
`cryptsetup --debug isLuks` seems fine(Luks headers etc.).
As far as I can tell the boot messages don’t report anything, except for the errors related to the ‘wrong’ password.

I tried to look into journalctl, but the entries stop hours before the system freeze occured (using `journalctl -D mounted-root/var/log/journalctl`) but maybe I’m doing it wrong.

While trying to use a keyfile to unlock (which, again, works manually but not on boot, although the keyfile and the luks volume are found), I regenerated the initramfs, so that shouldn't be the problem aswell.

I honestly don’t know what else to look for, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took out one of my RAMs and it magically works fine again. This seemed to be the cause for the freeze and for cryptsetup 'silently' failing.